# Update HTML element style parameter value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I update an element's `style` parameter using jQuery?

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="template" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:none;">blabla...</div>
```

Now I tried to use this:

```
$('#template').attr('style', '...');
```

And this:

```
$('#template').prop('style', '...');
```

...but not working.

Is there any working solution in jQuery?

UPDATE: I don't want to update the element's style. I just want to overwrite the `stlye` parameter's value directly.

Comment: $('#template').css('width', '100px');  did you try this?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to update the element's `css` parameter. I just want to overwrite the `style` parameter's value diretcly.

Answer (score 2):

To update existing style you can use jquery [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```js
$('#template').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="template" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:none;">blabla...</div>
```

jquery [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) add a custom attribute to the element. In your OP it will change attribute `style` with the new:

```js
$('#template').attr('style', 'color:red;border: solid 1px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="template" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid;">blabla...</div>
```

As you can see will keep only the new one. Same way will work [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` is the best way to manipulate styles with jQuery.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Your example could be done as:

`$('#template').css({'font-size', '2em'});`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **jQuery** `css` method, if you want to edit several properties at a time you need try something like this:

```
$('#template').css({
   'font-size' : '10px',
   'width' : '30px',
   'height' : '10px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating, Overwrite!

Ignore what is declared, and at run-time, the jquery will over-ride what was set with new values.  so, don't try to target the style property, simply over-load it.

```
$('#template').css({'color': 'blue', 'width':'200px'});
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

you could use the jquery css api for this refer: http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
 $('#template').css('width', '100px'); // to change the width
```

or if you have more than one css style property to change then, create a class and declare all your styles there and then use the jquery addClass API refer: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

```
 css:
  .someClass{ width:100px; opacity:0.5; color:blue}

 jquery:
   $('#template').addClass('someClass');
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#template', function() {
     $('#template').css({'color' : '#e8e8e8', 'width' : '25em'})
)};
```